# jQuery definition issue (for unobtrusive-ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although the solution works fine, I get the following error every time I load my page (at JQuery in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`)

> "GET",data:e.concat(a(this).serializeArray())})})})(***jQuery***);

[image]

Any idea why is this as my AJAX calls work perfectly - Its just bot annoying to see the error in console

Script loading sequance

```
 <script src="~/assets/plugins/feather-icons/feather.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/assets/plugins/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>

    <script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't pass `jQuery` if you don't need it, or it's not loaded.

Comment: It should be loaded because jQuery script reference is at the top of every other script reference .... Also this Ajax script requires jQuery to run, I am not sure why I see error in console where all Ajax calls are working fine

Comment: Updated my question with script loading sequence

Comment: sorry, missed in copy/paste, Just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change the sequence & keep **jQuery on top**, as -

```
<script src="~/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/feather-icons/feather.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-typehead/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/plugins/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>

<script src="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes the sequence matters. If this doesn't work, move `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js' at second preference after jQuery.

Comment: @TusharWalzade i tried that but still no luck, also i completely removed the reference and tried again , even without the script i get the same error

Comment: I've tried using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>` & it doesn't produce any error. So, please try using it & let's see.